# Mocking a File object to return a another File object

Tags: file, junit, mockito

I have a junit test, which send a httpRequest along with some parameter. Based on the parameter, it is reading / updating a  property file. After the operation I need to test if the content of the file is correctly read / updated.

Here, in test what I want is, instead reading / writing the original property file, it do these operation on some temp file similar to the original file. My question is,Is it possible to mock a File object to return other file object? As httpRequest is looking the file at specific location only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possibl. What you can do is , mock the file object , pass the temporary file path to the file object and using mockito.when-then method replace original file object with the mock object , that should do what you are looking for. if you need any further assistanse please copy your code

Comment: I really can't follow this.  Can you please spell it out in a bit more detail?  More specifically, how do you "pass the temporary file path to the file object", and how do you "replace original file object with the mock object"?  I can't think what either of these two instructions might mean.